# How to configure log of nvelocity?

Tags: c#, nvelocity

NVelocity seems to be creating a `nvelocity.log` in the root or our website.
Apparently it is using log4net, but it is not using our current log4net configuration because our logs are in another folder.

How can we change the location of the nvelocity.log file?

Comment: Here's the source: https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail/tree/master/MR2/NVelocity/src/NVelocity/Runtime/Log

Comment: Thanks @Amy, it was helpful to see the structure of logging files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that `nvelocity` is being initialized using the `SimpleLog4NetLogSystem`, the existing configuration (this is an old feature on the site) is telling nvelocity to use the `NullLogSystem`. I think that's why the file is created empty and never modified, `SimpleLog4NetLogSystem` is used at first but then the `NullLogSystem`. I think it is some bug on this version.

Anyway I found how to change the configuration file, at least in the version we are using (1.0.3324.33234):

```
var props = new ExtendedProperties();               
props.AddProperty("runtime.log", "Logs\\nvelocity.log");

Velocity.Init(props);
```

In later versions "**runtime.log**" is specified by the `NVelocity.Runtime.RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG` constant.

Also the Velocity.Init can receive a configuration file so you don't have to hardcode the name of the log file.